# get a unique brush for numbers

Tags: c#, wpf

I like to display some decimal numbers. As many as possible need to have a unique brush in WPF.

example

```
-1.00 (display in Green and Orange)
0.00 (display in Orange)
1.00 (display in Green)
2.00 (display in Red)
```

no specified pattern is needed.

---

RBG is to small for my case.

255 * 255 * 255 = 16 581 375

---

The color for a value have to be always the same.

---

```
public Brush GetValueColor(decimal value)
{
    //Generate Brush for value
    return myBrush;
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with my question but whatever. Just need a function to return a unique brush for every unique number. It doesn't mater how the numbers looks like.

Comment: you need to rephrase what the question here as it isnt clear what you want exactly

Comment: You do realize that anything beyond 8 bit per channel is not even visible to the human eye, right?

Comment: How many unique colors do you need?

Comment: @H.B. yes but there are other ways like gradient brushes and other solutions.

Comment: @Meleak the thread seems closed but anyway so many as possible with simple methods.

Comment: Wow, did we all got off on the wrong side of bed this morning? How does this kind of question get seven downvotes? It's an interesting question without an obvious simple solution. Maybe it could have been phrased better, but I had no trouble figuring out what the OP is asking.

Comment: FWIW: Here's one possible approach. To (almost) guarantee uniqueness, compute the SHA1 hash of the UTF-8 representation of the number and use bits from the hash to parameterise different aspects of the brush (color, choice of pattern, ...). This doesn't absolutely guarantee uniqueness, but it makes collisions unlikely; the more bits you use the better.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Look at the edit history, i knew that it was going to get closed when i first saw (i was the first to downvote in fact, later retracted of course) but now it seems comparatively fine, maybe flag it for mod attention.

Comment: @H.B.: Maybe I'm unavoidably biased by knowing the current version, but I can't see what was so confusing about the first version. The lack of info about the technology stack was the only real issue with it, and that was fixed *before* it was closed.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: I assure you, you now are too biased :)

Comment: He states he wants a unique brush color but 16,581,375 options is not enough.  He invalidated his own question.  Then he cannot even get RGB right. Even if English is not his first language first letter is first letter in any language. Of the three he got 1 right - green. I checked and Brush is RGB.

Comment: @BalamBalam: If you look closer at `Brush` you'll see that it is abstract so naturally the method should return something that derives from `Brush`. Like `SolidColorBrush` (which doesn't uphold the requirement so it can not be used), `RadialGradientBrush`, `LinearGradientBrush` etc.

Comment: @BalamBalam just to hang on... I don't really like the voting system on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always generate a `LinearGradientBrush` with `GradientStops` based on the bytes from value.ToString(). You can also reverse the `LinearGradientBrush` back to the decimal value if needed.

*GetValueColor*

```
public LinearGradientBrush GetValueColor(decimal value)
{
    LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush();
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value.ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i += 3)
    {
        byte red = byteArray[i];
        byte green = i < byteArray.Length - 1 ? byteArray[i + 1] : (byte)0;
        byte blue = i < byteArray.Length - 2 ? byteArray[i + 2] : (byte)0;
        brush.GradientStops.Add(
            new GradientStop(new Color {A = 255, R = red, G = green, B = blue },
                                            (double)(i+1) / byteArray.Length));
    }
    return brush;
}
```

*Reverse: GetColorValue*

```
public decimal GetColorValue(LinearGradientBrush brush)
{
    List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();
    foreach (GradientStop gradientStop in brush.GradientStops)
    {
        byteList.Add(gradientStop.Color.R);
        byteList.Add(gradientStop.Color.G);
        byteList.Add(gradientStop.Color.B);
    }
    return Convert.ToDecimal(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteList.ToArray()));
}
```